# Disable visual effects of a CSS class

Tags: javascript

On a site a CSS class is periodically added to an element by JavaScript.

I'd like not to show the visible effect of that class. In other words what I need is an effect similar to switching the class off in the development console of the browser. Let the class exist but without any consequences.

I understand that I can catch events and remove the class when it appears.

But maybe there is just a more simple way in my case?

In other words: there is a CSS class, I would like it to be present but without any visual effects. If it is impossible, that will also be an answer.

Comment: What is the purpose of the class? Could you just make another identifying class which doesn't change the style of the elements? Or possible add another class to these which negates any stylistic changes made by said class.

Comment: It seems strange to do so. So you want to catch events to periodically enable visual effects, but you don't want to catch events to periodically disable visual effects. You should probably just addClass, removeClass.

Comment: what the visual effects of that class which you are trying to clear ?  create css with same class and overwrite those visual effects with initial or inherit with !important

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do the trick in most circumstances. I imagine there are circumstances that would evade this, but I can't think of them.

Basically you need to iterate [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/styleSheets) collection, then iterate each rule contained within and compare the [`CSSStyleRule.selectorText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleRule/selectorText) for each rule against a regular expression.

Regular expressions can be faulty, so I've included a check against an element with the supplied class name using the [`Element#matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) method. That method can also provide false positives in the case where the element matches some other part of the selector, so the two together should reasonably prevent any false positives.

Once you have a list of all the CSS rules that apply to a given class, you can simply delete them all. This can be done in the same step as finding them, but I've done it separately in for example's sake.

```js
function findClassRules(name) {
  const element = document.createElement('div')
  element.classList.add(name)
  const regex = new RegExp(`\\\.${ name }([^\w]|$)`, 'i')
  
  const test = {
    rule: rule => {
      if('cssRules' in rule) {
        return test.sheet(rule)
      } else if('selectorText' in rule) {
        const selector = rule.selectorText
        return selector.match(regex) && element.matches(selector) && rule
      }
    },
    sheet: sheet => {
      const rules = Array.from(sheet.cssRules, test.rule).filter(Boolean)
      return rules.length && { sheet, rules }
    }
  }
  
  return Array.from(document.styleSheets, test.sheet).filter(Boolean)
}

function processSheet({ sheet, rules }) {
  rules.forEach(rule => {
    if('rules' in rule) {
      processSheet(rule)
    } else {
      sheet.deleteRule(rule)
      console.log(`Removed: ${ rule.cssText }`)
    }
  })
}

document.getElementById('clean').addEventListener('click', event => {
  findClassRules('test').forEach(processSheet)
}, false)
```

```css
.test { padding: 5px }
.test2 { padding: 10px }
@media screen {
  .test { margin: 15px }
}
```

```html
<p class="test">Hello world!</p>
<button id="clean">Remove CSS</button>
<style type="text/css">
.test { color: red }
</style>
<style type="text/css">
.test { border: 1px solid red }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this. Access the document's stylesheets and apply some sort of regex matching to figure out which rules are associated with the class in question. Then simply unset the styling on the rules. Note that just because the class name is found in the stylesheet rule doesn't mean it is the element being affected by the styles...but this should get you going in the right direction.

```js
function removeClassStyling(clazz) {
  var classRegex = new RegExp('\\.'+clazz.toLowerCase()+'\\b','i')

  for (var s=0; s<document.styleSheets.length; ++s) {
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[s];

    for(var r=0; r<sheet.cssRules.length; ++r) {
      var rule = sheet.cssRules[r];
      
      if(rule.selectorText && rule.selectorText.match(classRegex)) {
        var properties = Object.keys(rule.style);
        
        for(var p=0; p<properties.length; ++p){
          if(rule.style[properties[p]]) rule.style[properties[p]] = "";
        }
        
        console.log('removed styling for "'+clazz+'"');
      }
      
    }

  }
}


setTimeout(function(){ removeClassStyling('unwanted-class') }, 1500)
```

```css
.unwanted-class {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="unwanted-class"> Test </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

How about you comment the class in your css file

Comment: Please do consider commenting on the "comment" section if you don't have the answer for the question